# Expected number of duplicates when sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given that we have  items, each item has a probability of getting sampled $_$
for $=1,…,$, with the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{N}p_i=1$. If $K$ items are sampled **with replacement**, what is the probability of getting atleast one duplicate, and what is the expected number of duplicates in the sample?

Comment: " what is the probability of getting duplicates" - at least one duplicate? what happens if one items comes out three times or four times?

Comment: @quantinho Thanks for your reply. Yes, I used duplicates broadly, it includes one item getting sampled >2 times. For example a sampled list such as $x={1,1,1,2,2,2,2,4,5,6}$ contains duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the discrete variable that counts "duplicates" given $K$ samples with replacement and let $E(X)$ be the expected number of "duplicates" in the sample, meaning items that are sampled two or more times. To find it we can use binary variables and linearity of expectation. Let $Y$ be the number of items not sampled and $Z$ the number of items sampled only once, then $X=N-Y-Z$ and $E(X)=N-E(Y)-E(Z)$.
To find $E(Y)$ and $E(Z)$ we use binary variables, let $Y_i$ be the event "item $i$ is not sampled", then $P(Y_i)=(1-p_i)^{K}$. $Y$ is the number of events $Y_i$ that occur, so we can see $Y_i$ as a binary variable that is $1$ if the event occur and $0$ otherwise and $Y=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N} Y_i \space$.

$P(Y_i=1)=E(Y_i)=(1-p_i)^K$, hence $E(Y)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}E(Y_i)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-p_i)^K$.
For $E(Z)$ we use the same reasoning with $P(Z_i)=P(Bi(K,p_i)=1)=Kp_i(1-p_i)^{K-1}$, which is the brobability that item $i$ is sampled exactly once, hence $E(Z)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}E(Z_i)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}Kp_i(1-p_i)^{K-1}$.

So we can express $E(X)=N-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}(1-p_i)^K+Kp_i(1-p_i)^{K-1}$.

Now we want to find $P(X>0)$, given that $X$ can assume values ${0,1,...,N}$ this is $1-P(X=0)$ which is the complement to the probability of getting no duplicates, in other words sampling $K\le N$ different items (if $K>N$ then there is at least one duplicate).
To get the value of $P(X=0)$ we have to sum up all the probabilities of all subsets (ordered) of $K$ items to be sampled, which is $K!\displaystyle\sum_{S}\prod_{j\in S} p_j$ where $S\subset(1,2,...,N)$ and $|S|=K$.

If $\space \forall j=1,...,N \: p_j=\frac{1}{N}$ then we could express $P(X>0)$ in terms of $K$ and $N$. It would be $\displaystyle\binom{N}{K}\frac{K!}{N^K} \space$.